# Group By Count from Multiple Tables with conditions

Tags: sql, join, group-by, subquery

I have 3 different tables, country, city, and customer. Tables are shown below:

country table:

```
id   country_name
1    UK
2    US
3   Brazil
:    
n   Canada
```

city table

```
id  city_name  postal_code  country_id
1    London        30090         1
2    Dallas        20909         2
3    Rio           29090         3
4    Atlanta       30318         2
:
n    Vancouver     32230         n
```

customer table

```
id    customer_name     city_id
1        John             1
2        Pete             3
3        Dave             2
4        May              2
5        Chuck            4
6        Sam              3
7        Henry            3
```

***country.id is references city.country_id, and city.id is references customer.city_id

I want to write a query that can extract the country name, city name and the count of the customer of the associate city. But with one condition, the query will return all cities with more customers than the average number of customers of all cities

It will look something like below, this is the correct output

```
UK London 2
Brazil Rio 3
```

but I kept getting this output, which isn't correct

```
UK London 2
US Dallas 2
US Atlanta 1
Brazil Rio 3
```

I wrote a SQL query but it doesn't give me the result that I want

```
SELECT country.country_name, city.city_name, COUNT(customer.city_id) from country 
JOIN city on country.id = city.country_id 
JOIN customer on city.id = customer.city_id
Group by city_name,country.country_name;
```

I am wondering how can I do this and fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest your query into a subquery so that you can take the average value of the counts and compare the current count with it. If you're using an SQL that supports CTEs, you can use one e.g.

```
WITH cnts AS (
  SELECT country.country_name, city.city_name, COUNT(customer.city_id) AS cnt 
  FROM country 
  JOIN city on country.id = city.country_id 
  JOIN customer on city.id = customer.city_id
  GROUP BY city_name,country.country_name
)
SELECT *
FROM cnts
WHERE cnt > (SELECT AVG(cnt) FROM cnts)
```

Otherwise the query becomes more complex with the main query required as a subquery in the `WHERE` clause as well:

```
SELECT country.country_name, city.city_name, COUNT(customer.city_id) AS cnt 
FROM country 
JOIN city on country.id = city.country_id 
JOIN customer on city.id = customer.city_id
GROUP BY city_name,country.country_name
HAVING COUNT(customer.city_id) > (SELECT AVG(cnt) FROM (
  SELECT country.country_name, city.city_name, COUNT(customer.city_id) AS cnt 
  FROM country 
  JOIN city on country.id = city.country_id 
  JOIN customer on city.id = customer.city_id
  GROUP BY city_name,country.country_name
) cnts2)
```

In both cases the output for your sample data is:

```
country_name    city_name   cnt
Brazil          Rio         3
US              Dallas      2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=641a14bca45a00f844db50af55cfe907)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT cc.*
FROM (SELECT co.country_name, ci.city_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
             AVG(COUNT(*)) OVER () as avg_count
      FROM country co JOIn
           city ci
           ON co.id = ci.country_id JOIN 
           customer cu
           ON ci.id = cu.city_id
      GROUP BY ci.city_name, co.country_name
     ) cc
WHERE cnt > avg_count;
```